# TypeScript define interface/types for an object fetched from an API which has type unknown, but trying to assign defined types

Tags: typescript, loops, types, interface

Still learning TypeScript, so forgive me if I describe this incorrectly.

I have a function which fetches some data and returns a nested object which I loop over with forEach.
I have declared types for each value in the object I use, but still getting an error:

> Argument of type '(value: RaceInfo) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'RaceInfo'.ts(2345)

Please see code below:

```
interface Selection {
    date: string;
    time: string;
    venue: string;
}
```

```
interface RaceInfo {
     codes: {
         race_sc: string;
     };
     details: {
         venue: string;
  };
}
```

```
export default async function getSC(selection: Selection) {
  let sc;

  await fetch(`URL`,{method: "GET",})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.success) {
        Object.values(data.races).forEach((value: RaceInfo) => {
          if (
            value.codes.race_sc.slice(-4) === selection.time &&
            value.details.venue === selection.venue
          ) {
            sc = value.codes.race_sc;
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Could not fetch the races");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error:", error);
    });

  return sc;
}
```

I have found a way to this by changing the actual loop code, which works fine, but is this an acceptable way of writing strict TypeScript as I did not have to declare the types/interface for the returned object?

```
for (const key of Object.keys(data.races)) {
     const value = data.races[key];
     if (
        value.codes.race_sc.slice(-4) === selection.time &&
        value.details.venue === selection.venue
     ) {
        sc = value.codes.race_sc;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The contextual type of `value` is `unknown`. Giving it an explicit type of `RaceInfo` would break the type-safety of the callback. As far as the compiler is concerned, any value of `unknown` type can be passed into the callback. The error is stopping you from *changing* the definition to to a function which expects a value of type `RaceInfo`.

If you are sure that `Object.values(data.races)` can only ever be of type `RaceInfo[]`, you need to use a [*type assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
(Object.values(data.races) as RaceInfo[]).forEach((value) => /* ... */)
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. I knew this was a simple answer.
Thank you very much @Tobias!